# How can I extract data from cosmos db for a large json using query?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to extract certain information from a large json.

The json I have is as follows:

```
{
    "id": "abc",
    "doc1": {
        "documentName": "xyz",
        "documentUrl": "xyz",
        "documentType": ".xlsx",
        "contents": [
            {
                "Date": "2022-06-10T00:00:00",
                "Type": "Interaction",
                "Subject": "ABC",
                "Description": "My name is ABC."
            },
            {
                "Date": "2022-12-01T00:00:00",
                "Type": "Interaction",
                "Subject": "DEF",
                "Description": "I live in a town named DEF."
            },
            {
                "Date": "2023-03-15T00:00:00",
                "Type": "Interaction",
                "Subject": "IJK",
                "Description": "He is known as IJK."
            }
        ]
    },
    "doc2": {
        "documentName": "wyc",
        "documentUrl": "wyc",
        "documentType": ".xlsx",
        "contents": [
            {
                "Date": "2023-12-05T00:00:00",
                "Type": "Task",
                "Subject": "KLM",
                "Description": "She has a friend who is called as KLM.",
                "Status": "Completed"
            },
            {
                "Date": "2023-03-15T00:00:00",
                "Type": "Task",
                "Subject": "ROQ",
                "Description": "The dessert is named as ROQ.",
                "Status": "Completed"
            },
            {
                "Date": "2023-07-15T00:00:00",
                "Type": "Task",
                "Subject": "VDI",
                "Description": "We need to know the name of the school that VDI goes to.",
                "Status": "Open"
            }
        ]
    },
    "doc3": {
        "documentName": "ckl",
        "documentUrl": "ckl",
        "documentType": ".pdf",
        "contents": [
            {
                "pageNo": 1,
                "pageText": "Hi this place is known to have awesome desserts."
            },
            {
                "pageNo": 2,
                "pageText": "Hello World."
            },
            {
                "pageNo": 3,
                "pageText": "It is a beautiful day."
            },
            {
                "pageNo": 4,
                "pageText": "Sorry I think you have reached the wrong number."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to extract `"Date", "Subject", "Description"` from doc1, `"Date", "Subject", "Description" and "Status"` from doc2 and `"documentUrl" and "pageText"` (only from `"pageNo" 2 and 3`) from doc3.

I am expecting an output like this:
(for doc1 - all the dates, subjects and descriptions)

```
[
  {
   "contents":[
      {
        "Date": "2022-06-10T00:00:00",
        "Subject": "ABC",
        "Description": "My name is ABC."
      },
      {
        "Date": "2022-12-01T00:00:00",
        "Subject": "DEF",
        "Description": "I live in a town named DEF."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Kind of trying to extract the same for all the other documents, including doc2 and doc3, and for doc3, just the pageNo 2 and 3

Comment: First, please edit to show what you've attempted (you've only shown some input data and some desired output). Second: you seem to have created a very challenging data schema that will likely cause you problems: 1) you're using values as key names e.g. `"doc1"` and `"doc2"` (this is a modeling anti-pattern); 2) you don't have consistent data for each doc; 3) you have a potential *unbounded-array* issue, depending on how many things you store in `"contents"`. Also: why are `"doc1"`, `"doc2"`, and `"doc3"` in the same document in your container?

Answer (score 0):

You can see that I've set the array filter for pageNo 2 and 3 only. You can ofcourse alter this to have the data in their own fields instead of arrays like I have done below:

```
SELECT c.id, ARRAY(SELECT VALUE t.Date FROM t in c.doc1.contents) AS doc1Date,ARRAY(SELECT VALUE t.Subject FROM t in c.doc1.contents) AS doc1Subject, ARRAY(SELECT VALUE t.Description FROM t in c.doc1.contents) AS doc1Description,ARRAY(SELECT VALUE t.Date FROM t in c.doc2.contents) AS doc2Date, ARRAY(SELECT VALUE t.Status FROM t in c.doc2.contents) AS doc2Status, c.doc3.documentUrl AS doc3url, ARRAY(SELECT VALUE t.pageText FROM t in c.doc3.contents WHERE t["pageNo"] IN (2, 3)) AS doc3pageText FROM c WHERE c.id = "abc"
```

It will give a response like below.

```
[
    {
        "id": "abc",
        "doc1Date": [
            "2022-06-10T00:00:00",
            "2022-12-01T00:00:00",
            "2023-03-15T00:00:00"
        ],
        "doc1Subject": [
            "ABC",
            "DEF",
            "IJK"
        ],
        "doc1Description": [
            "My name is ABC.",
            "I live in a town named DEF.",
            "He is known as IJK."
        ],
        "doc2Date": [
            "2023-12-05T00:00:00",
            "2023-03-15T00:00:00",
            "2023-07-15T00:00:00"
        ],
        "doc2Status": [
            "Completed",
            "Completed",
            "Open"
        ],
        "doc3url": "ckl",
        "doc3pageText": [
            "Hello World.",
            "It is a beautiful day."
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: @AnupamChand - aside from the original question not having desired output, it still doesn't have any attempt at a query, or any specific query issue (it's just a requirement). Also, there are many issues with the OP's data model (I pointed these out in a comment under the question)